# How can I get python to read each line in a txt file and make seperate lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Say I have a .txt file with some integers.

```
#txt file called ints.txt

1,3
4
5,6
```

How can I get python to read each line and make them into separate lists?

The output I'm looking for:

```
['1','3']
['4']
['5','6']
```

I tried this code but it only prints the first element of the txt file as a list. I want it to print the subsequent elements too.

```
x = open("ints.txt", "r")
x = x.readline()
x = x.strip()
x = x.split(" ")


for i in x:

    print(x)

Output:
['1','3']
['1','3']
```

Appreciate the help, my friends :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('file/path') as f:
    lines = [i.strip().split(',') for i in f.readlines() if i.strip()]
```

To print the list of lists in each line, do this :

```
print(*lines, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This is great though it gives the output as one list containing multiple lists. Is there anyway to print each line out as separate lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try readlines method. Something like that.

```
with open("ints.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        items = line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
`with open("test.txt", "r") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        new_list = [x for x in line.split(" ")]
        print(new_list)
```